# Image zooming is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zooming

I am trying to add zoom effect to my images using jquery `JQZoom` plugin.

This is how my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="pb-left-column">
  <!-- product img-->        
  <div id="image-block" class="clearfix is_caroucel">
    <span id="view_full_size">
      <a class="jqzoom" title="" rel="gal1" href="img/products/1/1-tm_thickbox_default.jpg">
        <img src="img/products/1/1-tm_large_default.jpg" title="" alt="">
      </a>
    </span>
  </div> <!-- end image-block -->

  <!-- thumbnails -->
  <div id="views_block" class="clearfix">  
    <a id="view_scroll_left" class="" title="Other views" href="javascript:{}">Previous</a>
    <div id="thumbs_list">
      <ul id="thumbs_list_frame">
        <li id="thumbnail_1">
          <a rel="{ gallery: 'gal1', 
                    smallimage: 'img/products/1/1-tm_large_default.jpg',
                    largeimage: 'img/products/1/1-tm_thickbox_default.jpg'}"
             title="">
            <img class="img-responsive" id="thumb_1" src="img/products/1/1-tm_cart_default.jpg" alt="" title="" height="80" width="80">
          </a>
        </li>  
        .....
        .....
        .....
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- end thumbs_list -->
    <a id="view_scroll_right" title="Other views" href="javascript:{}">
      Next
    </a>
  </div> <!-- end views-block -->     
  <!-- end thumbnails -->                                                          
</div>
```

MY Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
    zoomType: 'innerzoom', 
    zoomWidth: 458, 
    zoomHeight: 458, 
    xOffset: 21, 
    yOffset: 0,
    title: false
  });
});
```

My problem is when I using this code, image zoom is not working correctly. Its working but not zooming.

This is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/40ht9a04/) with existing code.

Can anybody tell me what is the wrong with this?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to fix these errors first: http://i.imgur.com/IknoJxd.png

Comment: @Rvervuurt, I can not get those errors in my console..

Comment: I get those errors in my console when I open the fiddle.

Comment: Isn't it? But I cann't get. what would be the problem? I am using firebug

Comment: They show up in my console in Chrome.

Comment: what would be the issue this not to work? will it JS or CSS?

Comment: jQuery. Apparently there's something wrong with the library you have added. Try to fix those errors and see if that solves your problem. Then return instead of using the comments as chat :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85088/discussion-between-user3733831-and-rvervuurt).